# Python: Got an error when calling a function within itself

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I've made a simple dictionary program using python.

```
dictionary = {"testword" : "testmeaning"}
y = ["y", "Yes", "Y", "YES", "yes", "yep", "YEP", "Yep"]
n = ["n", "No", "N", "no", "NO", "nope", "Nope", "NOPE"]

def ans():
    ans = raw_input("Y/N")
    if ans in y:
        meaning = raw_input("Type the meaning.")
        dictionary[x] = meaning
        print "Added!. Thanks for using the dictionary."
        reload
    elif ans in n:
        print "Thanks for using the dictionary."
    else:
        print "Type either Y or N."
        ans()

def add_word():
    print "Do you want to add it?"
    ans()
def close_ans():
    close_ans = raw_input("Y/N")
    if close_ans in y:
        quit
    elif close_ans in n:
        in_dict()
    else:
        print "Type either Y or N"
        close_ans()

def close():
    print "Close?"
    close_ans()

def in_dict():
    global x
    x = raw_input("Type the word.")
    if x in dictionary:
        print dictionary[x]
        close()
    else:
        print "This word isn't in the dictionary yet."
        add_word()
        close()

in_dict()
```

The code is pretty self explanatory. I've made a dictionary with a word called "testword" with a value of "testmeaning". There is also a list of positive and negative answers which will be used to determine if the user agrees or declines in certain situations. It first calls the function in_dict which asks the user to type the word. If the word is in the dictionary, it prints the meaning and asks to close. If it is not, it asks the user if hey want to add it. Look through the code again if you don't understand it. If the user types something other then the word in the list y or n, it asks again. But, it doesn't work. It shows the following error if I type anything other than the word in y and n.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Prateek\Desktop\dictionary.py", line 46, in <module>
      in_dict()
    File "C:\Users\Prateek\Desktop\dictionary.py", line 43, in in_dict
      add_word()
    File "C:\Users\Prateek\Desktop\dictionary.py", line 20, in add_word
      ans()
    File "C:\Users\Prateek\Desktop\dictionary.py", line 16, in ans
      ans()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: You overwrite the function name with `ans = raw_input("Y/N")`

Answer (score 1):

By executing following sentence, you create local variable `ans`. That shadow global function `ans`.

```
ans = raw_input("Y/N")
```

use different name.

Answer (score 0):

That's because, inside function `ans`, you made `ans` equal a string with this line:

```
ans = raw_input("Y/N")
```

Doing this overshadowed the function `ans`.

To fix your problem, pick a different variable name or rename your function.